# Angular Pagination - Filtered results not updating total-items

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have two filters, one for pagination and one for a search query. It searches first, then paginates on the result.

Here is the html:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="pot in (filteredPots = (pots | search:potQuery | paginate:currentPageNumber.pots:itemsPerPage))">
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<pagination ng-model="currentPageNumber.pots" ng-change="paging(pots)" items-per-page="{{itemsPerPage}}" total-items="filteredPots.length" class="pagination-sm"></pagination>
```

From what I understand this is working correctly (I can add `{{ filteredPots.length }}` and it shows the value 10).

What I am trying to do is have the `total-items` value as the total array length (i.e. without the pagination which limits it to `itemsPerPage`).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... took a lot of trial and error.

Html is updated to:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="pot in (filteredPots = (searchedPots = (pots| search:potQuery) | paginate:currentPageNumber.games:itemsPerPage))">
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<pagination ng-model="currentPageNumber.pots" ng-change="paging(pots)" items-per-page="{{itemsPerPage}}" total-items="searchedPots.length" class="pagination-sm"></pagination>
```

What's changed? Instead of filtering the array `pots` with two seperated filters, I'm filtering the array `pots` on the filter `search:potQuery` and saving the resulting array as `searchedPots`, then the second filter uses `searchedPots` as the array, and saves that result as `filteredPots` (which isn't used).

I then have the length of the searched pots BEFORE pagination as `searchedPots`.